# View can be created in Access 2000?

Tags: ms-access, view

In Access 2000, can we create views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

SQL Server Views are called Queries in Access.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way in Access to use code to create a saved query is to use DAO to create a saved QueryDef. Something like this:

```
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("MyQuery", "SELECT * FROM MyTable;")

  Set qdf = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
```

That will work in all versions of Access with a DAO reference.

Comment: I am very puzzled indeed as to why this perfectly correct answer was down voted.

Comment: It's probably Aaron Kempf, retaliating for me flagging his anti-Access posts.

Answer (score 0):

"The CREATE VIEW and DROP VIEW statements can be executed only through the Jet OLE DB provider and ADO...". Taken from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977(v=office.10).aspx#acadvsql_views

Comment: They can also be executed in interactive Access if you're running in ANSI 92 SQL mode. I wouldn't recommend it, but the key is that you're not limited to ADO within Access itself.